# Heroku application error - react and node

Tags: heroku

I have created a react app with nodejs, I am getting an application error while starting my heroku application. I have updated heroku, created procfile, added node as engine. Still my application is not starting. Please help.
Here is my log file -

```
2021-09-01T11:44:33.891631+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-09-01T11:44:33.891717+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-09-01T11_44_33_888Z-debug.log
2021-09-01T11:44:33.962004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-01T11:44:34.090659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-01T11:46:07.443211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-castle-26018.herokuapp.com request_id=4bbb82b9-74a6-4ab1-a6a3-f4a3ed25c62b fwd="223.227.24.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-01T11:46:08.456373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quiet-castle-26018.herokuapp.com request_id=f004c10c-b1ba-4094-9b2d-456ced15cb7f fwd="223.227.24.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-01T11:46:25.484370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-castle-26018.herokuapp.com request_id=6de00b8d-640b-4ed2-ad30-a729d440acc3 fwd="223.227.24.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-01T11:46:26.648725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quiet-castle-26018.herokuapp.com request_id=4f5601a4-85c3-4798-ae53-1eeb37340edd fwd="223.227.24.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-01T12:02:59.299054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quiet-castle-26018.herokuapp.com request_id=789d2879-7ff3-4282-a405-1ed057163b41 fwd="223.227.24.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-01T12:03:00.191266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quiet-castle-26018.herokuapp.com request_id=3010eeac-283b-4eb5-8cdd-0300c2df979b fwd="223.227.24.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
Connection to log stream failed. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Heroku` by default uses Node.js build pack, which would not work for a react app, you would not have to change the build pack in the setting of that project.

This explains the issue better https://stackoverflow.com/a/68992661/16471757